# SQL command for reading all columns in the first row

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel sheet in which the first row contains title for all the columns. I want all the names in the first row.

What is the SQL command for reading all the entries in the first row?

If possible, I want to define the max-limit.

In addition: I want to enumerate all the column names.

Comment: If you're looking to import this then SQL has a method to just import the data directly into a table. Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish a bit more. I think it might help.

Comment: @Jon, I am just trying to enumerate all the titles that are present in row-1. That is, all the titles at row-0 from col-0 to col-100 (say). This I am planning to use it for a software that will show all the enumerated titles (read from the 1st row).

Comment: Don't forget that in an RDBMS, there is officially no ordering of the data until you impose an order on it, so there is no 'first row'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in Excel using a saved workbook, and it enumerates the column (field) names.

```
Sub ListFieldADO()

    strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    cn.Open strCon

    ''You can also use the name of a named range
    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
        Array(Empty, Empty, "Sheet1$")) 
    While Not rs.EOF
        Debug.Print "     " & rs!Column_Name
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to mention "HDR=No;" in your connection string. Then you can use the following query:

```
Select Top 1 * from [SheetName$]
```

"HDR=No" will specify that the first row DOES NOT contains the column names.

Being said that, I don't know if there is a SQL statement to get the column names from a table. If there is, then you can have HDR=Yes in the connection string and use that SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I'm understanding this right....but I think you're saying that you want to select the column names from a table:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = [YourTableName]
```

Comment: +1 thank you, @Lloyd Can I use sheetname instead of table_name

Comment: It looks to me like I may have actually not understood this after all.  I gave you the command to do this in SQL Server.  It looks like several of us were under the impression that this was an SQL question.  VBA seems more appropriate here and it looks like Remou is already taking you down the right track there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Top 1 * into #temp from [SheetName$]

use tempdb

sp_help #temp.
```

By this, you can get the column names of the `#temp` table. Again, you have to change the database to:

```
use yourDBName
```

Put the data in a temporary table and read the properties of the temporary table and from that you can get the list of column names.